# Pick Query Distinct Rows

Tags: pick

How do you select distinct rows from PICK database.
Here's my query.
I get lots of duplicate rows.

SELECT ARIVAL WITH A.PROD.NO AND WITH WH.AR.DATE >= "01/01/18" AND WITH STATUS = "C"

Is there any online documentation for Pick Queries?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation here: https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/index.jsp

Look for the WHEN clause and see if that helps.